# Centering an image that is in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have an image in an anchor tag, and I need to center it.

I have managed to do so using this technique that I just came across messing about in the DOM inspector: http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3m/

it uses:

```
display: table;
margin 0 auto;
```

I tried using:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: (?)px;
```

but I found it wasn't actually centering it unless I messed with the width a lot which isn't really very good as anchor tag widths seem to not work as well (imo), it was like basically using a margin-left.

Curious as to whether any of you have used this before or found an even better technique as display: table isn't supported on IE 7 and back

Comment: what is your question? Do you need to horizontal/vertical center the image in your anchor tag or you need to center the anchor tag in the container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center;` on the #container to center elements within it.
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3m/3/

Comment: Yeah that does work, I feel ridiculous for not thinking of it, cheers mate

Comment: If this isn't working for you, check that the container is of the correct width (and not sized to the child `img`), and has an appropriate display value such as `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

use -ms-flexbox supported by all browser. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3m/5/)

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    height:600px;
    background: red;
}

.centre{ 
height: 100%;
    width:100%;

/* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:center;
-ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: please note newer browsers just use [`display : flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Answer (score 1):

It will work out for you..

```
.center
{
width: 100%;
display:block
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e3m/6/)

Try:

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    height:600px;
    background: red;
    display: table-cell; /* <-- allows use of vertical align */
    text-align:center; /* <-- horizontal centering */
    vertical-align:middle; /* <-- vertical centering */
}
```

Use the above and you wont need any more CSS for the `img`

Answer (score 0):

you can add to container `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle;`